# Factorize $(5a + \frac23)^2* (2a - \frac12)^2$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I found this question in my textbook - 
$$\left(5a + \dfrac23\right)^2\cdot \left(2a - \dfrac12\right)^2$$
I think it is already factorized but is there a way I can factorize it some more ? 
I tried combining both the terms but to no avail. I just don't know how to go about doing this one.

Comment: you are already writing in the linear factor.u can simplify it can't factorize more.

Answer (score 1):

The only simplification I can think of here is:$$(5a + \dfrac23)^2* (2a - \dfrac12)^2=\frac{(15a+2)^2}{9}\cdot\frac{(4a-1)^2}{4}=\frac{((15a+2)(4a-1))^2}{36}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ 
\frac{(2+a(7-60a))^2}{36} $$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is not particularly helpful to post only the final answer. First of all, you haven't explained how to arrive at this answer. Secondly, it may be more helpful in future to explain how to proceed from where the OP is stuck; the question is of the form "is there a way?", rather than "what is the answer?".

Answer (score 0):

You are quite right in saying that it is factorized allready. You could clean it up a bit by getting rid of the fractions in the factors, but that's all.

Comment: How would I go about cleaning up the fractions ?

Comment: You can see it in the other answers. The endresult is someting like $2^{-2}3^{-2}\left(15a+2\right)\left(4a-1\right)$. But I tell you that it is a kind of 'silly' question (no not yours, but of the textbook). Factorization has been done allready.